# query none null values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I tried to implement the following mysql command try to get rows with none null values,

here is the table tbtext:

```
  id       text
     1 
     2     number2
     3     number3
     4     


   create table tbtext(
     id unsigned int auto_increment primary key,
     text char(7)
      )
```

I tried `select * from tbtext where text is not null`, but it returns the whole rows and doesn't return row 3 and row 4. I am new to mysql, can anyone help me with it, thanks in advance.

Comment: please paste your table definition by `show create table tbtext`

Comment: Rows 3 and 4 have nothing in common. Is it a typo in the question?

Comment: @alvaro, that's mean a null string

Comment: @smith - What null string? Rows 3 is "number3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `text` contains empty strings, and not NULL. The best thing to do would be to replace those empty strings with NULL, but you could also use this query :

```
-- ...
WHERE text <> '';
```

Please note however that empty strings *are* information, where NULL means *lack* of information. You should definitely not have empty strings if that's not what you're trying to do.